# developed (simplified) form of a Euclidean projection onto a convex set

Tags: convex-optimization

$\|\cdot\|$ is Euclidean norm. I minimize a convex and differentiable function $f : \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with constraint. By applying the projected gradient method I get this :

\begin{equation}
     x_{k+1} = \arg\min_{y: \| y - x_1 \| \leq D} \{ \frac{1}{2} \| y - x_k + \eta \nabla f(x) \|^2\}
\end{equation}
In the slides on the internet, the authors, after simplification obtain

\begin{equation}
     x_{k+1} = \arg\min_{y: \| y - x_1 \| \leq D} \{ \frac{1}{2} \| y - x_k\|^2 + \eta \langle \nabla f(x), y - x_k \rangle \}
\end{equation}

Me, when I develop I get this :

\begin{align}
     x_{k+1} &= \arg\min_{y: \| y - x_1 \| \leq D} \{ \frac{1}{2} \| (y - x_k) + \eta \nabla f(x) \|^2\} \\
      &= \arg\min_{y: \| y - x_1 \| \leq D} \{ \frac{1}{2} (\ \| y - x_k\|^2 + 2\eta \langle \nabla f(x), y - x_k \rangle + \eta^2 \langle \nabla f(x), \nabla f(x) \rangle \ ) \} \\
      &= \arg\min_{y: \| y - x_1 \| \leq D} \{\ \frac{1}{2}  \| y - x_k\|^2 + \eta \langle \nabla f(x), y - x_k \rangle + \frac{\eta^2}{2} \langle \nabla f(x), \nabla f(x) \rangle \ \}
\end{align}
As you can see, I have a third term $\frac{\eta^2}{2} \langle \nabla f(x), \nabla f(x) \rangle $ that stands out. Is my method correct? What demonstration makes it possible to obtain the results of these authors?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimization is over $y$, and thus the third term can be viewed as a constant as it does not depend on $y$. Obviously $\arg\min_y \{f(y) + \mathrm{const} \}= \arg\min_y f(y)$.

(And it seems you made a typo: should be $\nabla f(x_k)$ instead of $\nabla f(x)$)

Comment: Indeed  it's $\nabla f(x_k)$.